# Calculation result not showing in <h2>. Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a percentage calculator which is working. However the result is showing only in my `input`. It is not showing in my `h2`. I want the result to display in both the `input` and `h2`. Is this possible?

```js
$(document).on("change keyup blur live", ".ChangeCalulator", function() { // For:- = Topper To Current %
  let formContainer = $(this).closest('.section')
  var first = Number($(formContainer).find('.CalcFrom').val()); // = Topper Price
  var second = Number($(formContainer).find('.CalcTo').val()); // = Current Price
  var minus = second - first; // 2000 - 1000 = {1000 = minus}
  var divide = (minus / first); // 1000 / 1000 = 1
  var multiply = divide * 100; // 1 * 100 = 100%
  $(formContainer).find('.CalcResult').val(Number(multiply).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <p style="margin:5px 0 5px;color:blue;font-size:18px;">Topper to current</p>
  <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator CalcFrom" value="1000">
  <input type="text" class="CalcTo ChangeCalulator" value="">
  <input type="text" class="CalcResult" value="">
  <h2 class="CalcResult"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: h2 dont have a value, so use `.text()`

Comment: can you paste full codes ?

Comment: I want result in noth <input> and <h2>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `val()`, and only `input` elements have values. To show the output in the `h2` use the `text()` method.

In addition, I'd suggest separating the selectors, otherwise your code will attempt to add a `value` to the `h2` and a text node to the `input`, which is invalid.

Finally, use the `input` event instead of multiple events you bound to, and also don't double-wrap your jQuery objects, it's a waste.

```js
$(document).on("input", ".ChangeCalulator", (e) => {
  let $formContainer = $(e.target).closest('.section')
  let first = Number($formContainer.find('.CalcFrom').val());
  let second = Number($formContainer.find('.CalcTo').val());
  let result = ((second - first) / first * 100).toFixed(2);
  
  $formContainer.find('input.CalcResult').val(result);
  $formContainer.find('h2.CalcResult').text(result);
});
```

```css
.section p {
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <p>Topper to current</p>
  <input type="text" class="CalcFrom ChangeCalulator" value="1000">
  <input type="text" class="CalcTo ChangeCalulator" value="">
  <input type="text" class="CalcResult" value="">
  <h2 class="CalcResult"></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.section .ChangeCalulator').on('keyup',function(){
    var result = ((parseFloat($('.CalcTo').val()) - parseFloat($('.CalcFrom').val())) / parseFloat($('.CalcFrom').val()) * 100).toFixed(2);
    if(isNaN(result)) 
    {
      result='';
    }
    $('.CalcResult').val(result);
    $('.CalcResult').text(result);
});
```

```css
.section p {
  margin: 5px 0 5px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<-- The issue is because you are  using val(), and only input elements have values. To show the output in the h2 use the text() method. -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
  <p>Topper to current</p>
  <input type="text" class="CalcFrom ChangeCalulator" value="1000">
  <input type="text" class="CalcTo ChangeCalulator" value="">
  <input type="text" class="CalcResult" value="">
  <h2 class="CalcResult"></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know answer of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630166/tablesorter-is-not-sorting-calculation-result-columns-jquery-javascript